# How to add debug logging to C# .NET Core unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, .net-core

I'm trying to add some simple console logging to my unit tests in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and am having trouble since the logging configuration changed.

I currently have this code, which creates a logger for my class, "DataTests":

```
// Create logger for our unit tests
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

var logger = factory.CreateLogger<DataTests>();
```

But it doesn't log to the debug window, and I can't configure it.  I would like to do something like

```
factory.AddDebug();
```

But that extension is now obsolete and no longer available.  It is replaced by an extension on ILoggingBuilder instead of ILoggerFactory.  This is how it's used in file *program.cs*:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json",
                      optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            // Requires `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    webHost.Run();
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the ILoggingBuilder from my unit test class. How can I do this?  It's a shame it's so complicated to add a simple logger to a simple unit test class - this should be built in by default I would think.

Comment: The framework is heavily modularized so that you can customize what you need without a bunch of boilerplate bloat included where it is not needed.

Comment: Are you using the DI framework just to get a logging instance, or do you leverage the DI framework in tests for other reasons?

Comment: I am using DI in the app but not in the unit tests. In the unit tests I manually inject the dependencies.

Comment: Java has logging for tests out of the box. Why C#/.NET makes it so hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`AddLogging(IServiceCollection, Action<ILoggingBuilder>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.loggingservicecollectionextensions.addlogging?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions_AddLogging_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILoggingBuilder__) overload:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(builder => {
        builder.AddDebug();  //<--

        //...add other logging configuration as needed
    })
    .BuildServiceProvider();

//...
```

Which gives access to the builder via a configuration delegate.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  However, now I guess I need to figure out how to set the verbosity, without having an appSettings file (since it's a unit test), because I am not seeing any of the EF logging information in the debug window.

Comment: @RandyGamage EF logging? is this a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: This is an integration test, as I'm actually hitting the database. It's actually part of a workshop I am developing, to show students the actual SQL generated for various simple EF linq->SQL, and show them which ops will operate in the db, and which will be evaluated locally, etc. so I wanted to show warnings and ef logging as part of the workshop.  But I am only seeing those log outputs when the actual app is run, not in the UTs.

Comment: Just to clarify I also have unit tests that run against an in-memory EF database, but the requirements are the same. I want to see the logs of the generated SQL in both cases.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using .NET Core, I'll assume you're also using [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit).

xUnit uses a specific interface for logging to the console, `ITestOutputHelper`, which gets injected by xUnit itself in test fixture constructors.

There is a NuGet package, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Divergic.Logging.Xunit, that can create an `ILogger<T>` wrapper around `ITextOutputHelper` to be able to pass them to systems that require the `ILogger` interface.

I don't use a dependency injection framework for my xUnit tests and I end up wiring them up myself with mock versions, so here's what I do.

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public sealed class MyTestFixture
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyTestFixture(ITestOutputHelper helper)
    {
        _logger = helper.BuildLoggerFor<MyClass>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FooBar()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass(_logger);
        myClass.WizzBang();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually using mstest, but will probably switch to xunit.  This is very handy information I will keep on file, thank you.

Comment: This should probably have an example of how to send a log message using XUnits logger.

Comment: @FoxDeploy not quite sure what you mean, the example shows how to get an `ILogger<T>` instance.

Comment: Perfect. Prefer this over adding `Console.Writeline` in my code. Is there a way to add to all test classes by default?

Answer (score 5):

Following up on [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062586/how-to-add-debug-logging-to-c-sharp-net-core-unit-tests/57062832#57062832), per the xUnit documentation in *[Capturing Output](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output)*, it is simple to add console logging to any unit test as per the example from their site:

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

public class MyTestClass
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var temp = "my class!";
        output.WriteLine("This is output from {0}", temp);
    }
}
```